# Get Data From Postgres Table At every nth interval

Tags: postgresql

Below is my table and i am inserting data from my windows .Net application at every 1 Second Interval. i want to write query to fetch data from the table at every nth interval for example at every 5 second.Below is the query i am using but not getting result as required. Please Help me

```
CREATE TABLE table_1
(
  timestamp_col timestamp without time zone,
  value_1 bigint,
  value_2 bigint
)
```

This is my query which i am using

```
select timestamp_col,value_1,value_2
from (
    select timestamp_col,value_1,value_2,
           INTERVAL '5 Seconds' * (row_number() OVER(ORDER BY timestamp_col) - 1 )
           + timestamp_col as r
    from table_1
) as dt
Where r = 1
```

Comment: So every seccond new rows are inserted and every interval `x` you will be executing query you asking for to fetch all rows insertet since last query execution?

Answer (score 0):

Use [date_part()](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-EXTRACT) function with [modulo](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-math.html) operator:

```
select timestamp_col, value_1, value_2
from table_1
where date_part('second', timestamp_col)::int % 5 = 0
```